# Linux $PATH variables, soft links, and Command Not Found

Tags: linux, path, symbolic-link

I am having problems with symbolic links and the $PATH variable.

I have a directory:

```
# /usr/rulerX/square
```

where /usr/rulerX/square is a symbolic link such that:

```
# ls -la
square --> square.hg.current
```

My path variable is set as:

```
# echo $PATH
/usr/rulerX/square/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

I have a file, runSquare, under /usr/rulerX/square.hg.current/bin/

Here's the problem:

```
# runSquare
runSquare: Command Not Found
```

What gives? If I set /usr/rulerX/square.hg.current/bin to the PATH; everything works fine.  However, if I have the symbolic link (just 'square'), it can't find the file.

- I am using CentOS with csh

Comment: setenv PATH /usr/rulerX/square/bin:$PATH will NOT allow me to execute.

Comment: setenv PATH /usr/rulerX/square.hg.current/bin:$PATH however WILL allow me. What's the matter here?

Comment: It is good idea to avoid running as root as much as possible. Consider sticking to an unprivileged account and using `sudo` on those operation that require elevated privilege.

Answer (score 2):

Some shells (including `csh` and derivatives) maintain a preprocessed list of files in the directories along `PATH` to increase searching speed. If your shell is doing that you need to instruct it to rebuild the list.

Typically there is a shell built-in for this, and it is often called `rehash`.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind; it appears that after a few minutes; the $PATH to /bin/ propagated to the symbolic link.

It could be a bug?